# Property is undefined | React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and I get this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`. I understand that my `value` is undefined, but I have no idea why. Any suggestions?

```
export default class DateInput extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.value)
    return (
      <div>
        {parseDate(this.props.value)}
        <div>
          <Datetime
            input={true}
            onChange={e => {
              this.props.onChange(parseDate(e.target.value))
            }}
          />
        </div>
        {/* <input
        type='text'
        onChange={(e) => {
          this.props.onChange(parseDate(e.target.value))
        }} /> */}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Thanks for reading my question!

Comment: And why the java tag?

Comment: Ops! Must have misclicked. Thanks for editing.

Comment: What is `Datetime`? Does it pass full blown event to `onChange` handler?

Comment: `Datetime` being a component, I don't think there is any event passed to `onChange`. Try instead `onChange={e => {console.log(e)}}`. Do you get something in the log?

Comment: @Chris. I think you're right, I thought about that too.
When I log `e` I get back a momentJS object (which is good) and inside of it I can see the date (what I want). Now I just need to pass it to `value`, or am I wrong?

Comment: @MartinNordström, pass it to value? Is that a function?

Comment: The error doesn't say the value property is undefined. It says the container for value is undefined. If you are using this.props.value, then this.props is undefined.

Comment: Are you passing the prop value here? `<DateInput value={//some value} />`

Comment: @Chris `value` is just a prop that im validating later for my output. it basically checks if the string it valid and later outputs it with `moment`:
`return <div>{moment(this.props.value).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')}</div>`

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass the prop value when using the DateInput component like

`<DateInput value={//some value} onChange={//some function} />`